# No state latency improvement using local SSD in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running a Flink 1.14.2 application that processes hundreds of thousands of events per minute.
This data is partitioned and I have multiple state data structures to read/write.

In case it is of any interest, I run 6 slots per TM, 15g memory, 6g for job manager.

I want to improve the processing speed so I enabled state latency metrics to measure the impact of using local SSD disks instead of EBS volumes:

```
state.backend.latency-track.keyed-state-enabled: true
state.backend.latency-track.sample-interval: 10
state.backend.latency-track.history-size: 256
```

I have run the same application using the local SSDs for rocksdb (mounted under /mnt1/) and regular EBS (/tmp/). However I am not getting any improvements according to the metrics.

This is the min put latency using the SSD:
[image: ssd latency]

And this is using EBS:
[image: ebs latency]

I also run a benchmark on the disk and it confirms that the SSD is faster:

```
# EBS
Jobs: 4 (f=4): [r(4)] [100.0% done] [12012KB/0KB/0KB /s] [3003/0/0 iops] [eta 00m:00s]
  read : io=731944KB, bw=12199KB/s, iops=3049, runt= 60001msec
    slat (usec): min=125, max=6473, avg=1309.29, stdev=236.23
    clat (usec): min=2, max=25821, avg=19674.13, stdev=2309.38
     lat (msec): min=1, max=27, avg=20.98, stdev= 2.46
```

```
# SSD
Jobs: 4 (f=3): [f(1),r(3)] [100.0% done] [172.1MB/0KB/0KB /s] [44.3K/0/0 iops] [eta 00m:00s]
  read : io=2048.0MB, bw=177079KB/s, iops=44269, runt= 11843msec
    slat (usec): min=31, max=2346, avg=88.67, stdev=16.58
    clat (usec): min=1, max=6572, avg=1352.79, stdev=118.15
     lat (usec): min=77, max=6829, avg=1441.46, stdev=124.80
```

Why am I not seeing any improvement in the latency metrics?

Comment: Relying on Flink's built-in latency metrics can be misleading -- see https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/explainers/flink/understanding-measuring-and-reducing-latency-in-your-apache-flink-application/ for more on this.

Comment: Are you only looking at the min latency? In the best case, the disk doesn't play much of a role with RocksDB. What if you look at something like the mean, or p95 latency?

Comment: Looking at p95 latency I get similar results for both EBS and local SSD disks. Where do I look to measure the impact of SSD then? Is end-to end-test the only way?

Comment: It's possible, if RocksDB has been given enough memory relative to the amount of state, that the disk isn't a significant bottleneck. But yes, if you want meaningful measurements you'll have to instrument and measure the actual latency.